# #define and #ifdef macro in Rust

Tags: rust, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to rewrite this C++ code into Rust?

```cpp
#define is_unionfind_imported
class UnionFind {
};

class Kruskal {
#ifndef is_unionfind_imported
    #error "UnionFind not imported"
#endif
    UnionFind u;
};

int main() {
}
```

### Why, in the first place?

I often do competitive programming in Rust. In competitive programming, users usually register the source codes of frequently used data structures as *snippets*.

For example, in my case, this code is inserted from `~/snippets/union_find.rs` when I execute `:I unionfind` command in Vim:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct UnionFind {
    /* ... */
}
impl UnionFind {
    /* ... */
}
```

Also, when I execute `:I kruskal` in Vim, this code is inserted from `~/snippets/kruskal_method.rs`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Kruskal {
    u: UnionFind,
    /* ... */
}
impl Kruskal {
    fn new(/* ... */) -> Self {
        /* ... */
        Self {
            u: UnionFind::new(0),
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is `Kruskal` depends on `UnionFind`. If I manually execute `:I UnionFind` and `:I Kruskal`, there is no problem, but I often forget to first import `UnionFind`. Then the compiler says

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `UnionFind` in this scope
```

but I'd like to make this error message more user-friendly (e.g. `UnionFind is not imported. Execute :I unionfind in Vim.`).

And please note

- Module system cannot be used in competitive programming environment. (Only a single source file can be submitted.)
- I don't want to replicate `UnionFind` code in `Kruskal` snippet for maintainability.
- Implementing a dependency management system in my snippet inserter (i.e. the backend of `:I` command) is the last resort.

Comment: Rust has conditional compilation based on configuration options, but those cannot be set from source code, as far as I'm aware, only as flags to `rustc` or in `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cooked up a hacky solution.

```rs
#![allow(unused)]

mod placeholders {
    pub struct UnionFind;
    pub const UNION_FIND_IMPORTED: bool = false;
}

use placeholders::*;

// Start snippet
struct Kruskal {
    u: UnionFind,
}
const _: () = if !UNION_FIND_IMPORTED {
    panic!("UnionFind is not imported. Execute :I unionfind in Vim.");
};
// End snippet

// Start snippet
// struct UnionFind;
// const UNION_FIND_IMPORTED: bool = true;
// End snippet

fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}
```

The way this works is that when the `UnionFind` snippet is not present, it is pulled from the glob import. This means `UnionFind` is always present. In order to check if it's the right one, the constant `UNION_FIND_IMPORTED` is present next to both `UnionFind` structs. This is then compile-time evaluated with `const _: ()`, which will compile-panic when the import constant is false.

Pros:

- Custom error message
- Single file
- No CLI args needed

Cons:

- Requires you to have a placeholder module with all your types and the same implemented methods and traits as your real types so that the compiler doesn't stop before const evaluation
- Extra constants

Comment: Thank you. I think this meets my need though the con *Requires you to have a placeholder module with all your types and **the same implemented methods** and traits as your real types* is, well..., maybe too heavy to use in reality. By the way, in the second snippet, maybe `pub` is redundant?

Comment: @ynn Yeah, the pub was a copy-paste mistake. Doesn't really affect anything though.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'd like to make this error message more user-friendly (e.g. UnionFind is not imported. Execute :I unionfind in Vim.).

Changing error messages is not directly possible with Rust.

Considering you work with snippets, have you tried adding UnionFind into your Kruskal snippet?

You can also use modules within a source file.

For example, you could replace  `~/snippets/kruskal_method.rs` with this:

```
mod kruskal {
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
    struct UnionFind {
        /* ... */
    }
    impl UnionFind {
        /* ... */
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Kruskal {
        u: UnionFind,
        /* ... */
    }
    impl Kruskal {
        pub fn new(/* ... */) -> Self {
            /* ... */
            Self {
                u: UnionFind::new(0),
            }
        }
    }
}

use kruskal::Kruskal;
```

This way, you'll always get UnionFind with your code, but nothing else will change.

Comment: I'm sorry if my intention was ambiguous but the OP says *I don't want to replicate UnionFind code in Kruskal snippet for maintainability.* I meant I don't want to embed UnionFind into Kruskal.

Comment: I apologize, I missed that in your post. In that case, I don't think your problem can be solved, you'll have to rely on Rust's error messages. Maybe you can still use mod {} blocks and use statements, but I haven't checked what error message that  would return.